# Add the "Unanswered" menu to Stack Overflow, including the international ones

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, unanswered-questions, navigation, international-sites

All StackExchange sites have "Unanswered" menu item in their navigation. For example this one:

[image: Stack Exchange "Unanswered" menu item]

Except for Stack Overflow and its localized versions. While the menu (AKA left nav) for Stack Overflow is different from every other site (although I don't see obstacles to add "Unanswered" menu item there too)

[image: Stack Overflow screenshot]

menu items for localized Stack Overflow look the same as the rest of the network websites except missing "Unanswered" menu item. Screenshots for SO in Russian and SO in Portugese (but the same is true for SOes and SOja):

[image: Stack Overflow in Russian]

[image: Stack Overflow in Portugese]

So can the "Unanswered" menu item be added for all localized Stack Overflow sites and probably Stack Overflow itself?

---

Discussions on local Metas:

- [Russian](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9088/15479).
- [Portuguese](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7944/125288).
- [Spanish](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4339/99796).
- [Japanese](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3093/30081).

Comment: i would be happy to see it.

Comment: You can easily get the unanswered questions using a custom filter.

Comment: @Luuklag 1) You need to put efforts for this, 2) This is non-uniformity with other SE sites.